# Unexpected token: ) in findAll and findByKeyIn with Spring and Eclipselink JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Why do the following two simple integration tests fail, using Spring 1.5.4.RELEASE and Eclipselink 2.6.4?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApp.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
public class DbDummyIT {

    @Autowired
    private DbDummyRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void findAllFails() {
        List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
        List<DbDummy> result = repo.findAll(keys);
        assertThat(result.isEmpty()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void findByKeyInFails() {
        List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
        List<DbDummy> result = repo.findByKeyIn(keys);
        assertThat(result.isEmpty()).isTrue();
    }

}
```

Based on:

```
@Entity
@UuidGenerator(name = DbDummy.KEY_GENERATOR)
public class DbDummy {

    public static final String KEY_GENERATOR = "KeyGenerator";

    @Id
    @Column(name = ColumnName.KEY, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = KEY_GENERATOR)
    public String key;

}

@Repository
public interface DbDummyRepository extends JpaRepository<DbDummy, String> {

  List<DbDummy> findByKeyIn(List<String> keys);

}
```

Both tests fail with a JpaSystemException when calling the `find` queries. The error message is:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ) in statement [SELECT Key FROM DBDUMMY WHERE (Key IN ((?,?)))]
Error Code: -5581
Call: SELECT Key FROM DBDUMMY WHERE (Key IN ((?,?)))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=DbDummy sql="SELECT Key FROM DBDUMMY WHERE (Key IN (?))")
```

The statement looks indeed wrong to me. Doesn't `Key IN ((?, ?))` query for a list of bi-valued tuples? Shouldn't a list of strings should be queried as `Key IN (?, ?)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a long-living bug in Eclipselink: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477

Answer (score 0):

Try to change type to `Collection<String> keys` instead of `List<String> keys`. According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), this should be Collection, may be Spring thinks it is your custom method, not query method.

Comment: Gave it a try with `Collection` and (while I was at it) `Iterable`, but doesn't help. The fact that we get a JpaSystemException and it's got  SQL inside also seems to prove that Spring *does* recognize methods declared with `List`.